# convert VB code to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm a beginner in programming and i would like to know how can i translate the following code into C#

```
Dim arrayAlumnos(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1) As Registro
```

Comment: http://bit.ly/1AfvvVY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To preserve the array idea I'd probably write it like:

```
var arrayAlumnos = new Registro[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
```

But you could say this too:

```
Registro[] arrayAlumnos = new Registro[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
```

But ChaosPandion is right... a List is what you'd want to use most likely.

Comment: @user3748983 stop spamming the same msg please. That error has nothing to do with the question. This answer is correct.

Comment: What is the difference between the two code lines?
I don't know what is the best to implement

Comment: The difference is that your explicitly declaring the second one as Registo[], where in the first example by using var, your having the compiler figure out what it is.

Comment: Actually, VB arrays are declared using the upper bound, not the length as in C#, so a proper translation will use "ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count" as the array size.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using a list so I think this is the proper translation.

```
List<Registro> students = new List<Registro>();
```

Comment: Is it the correct code `Registro[] arrayAlumnos = new Registro[ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count];` ? I did it using an online converter

Comment: What you have is a literal translation.

Comment: Yep! :D But 'm getting the following error :( 
in the return

return arrayAlumnos; //<-Here
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Registro[]' to 'Registro' 

MetaInfo: i'm doing this inside a loop
arrayAlumnos[i] = loRegistroDia;

Comment: @user3748983 - Your question doesn't go beyond the scope of declaring a variable. You'll need to provide more info as to what you are doing (IE: Show more code).

Answer (score 0):

you'll probably have a lot of one off questions like this going through your travels of conversion, might want to take a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx

The basic idea behind the creation in C# is...

```
~ObjectType~ ~varName~ = new ~type~(~implement a type constructor here~);
```

anything in between ~~s you'll need to plug in the appropriate information.  For your case it would likely be:

```
Registro[] arrayAlumnos = new Registro[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1];
```

Kind of hard since it's a different spoken language but based on your variable name i'm guessing it's an array, though as others pointed out it could easily be created as a list.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, if you want to convert a lot of code from VB to C#, you can use [the ILSpy disassebler](http://ilspy.net/).  You can do this even if you don't have the original VB code.  Do this:

1. Compile the VB code into a *.exe or a *.dll.
2. Open the *.exe or *.dll file in ILSpy.
3. In the language dropdown, select VB.  (It's values are C#, VB, and MSIL).